# echo two tables issues required to post twice (mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql

I finally get reviews to work, which will allow user to post their review about the product and display them in a review page with product details, however I can't get it to work perfectly. When a user posts their review, it will update in the table but only the second post will show up. 
The following image is from the test i was running,

- [Before posting a review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzhz2.jpg)
- [After posting the first review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVked.jpg)
- [After posting the second review](http://i.imgur.com/%20Xjp4O22.png)

As the images display, the first review will never show up, only starting from the second and above,

Here my code for review page **updated with full code**

```html
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}  //start session
if (!isset($_SESSION['client_ID'])) {
 //echo "<script>alert('not logged in');</script>";
 header("Location: index.html"  );
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Games, Gaming, PS4, PS3, XBOX, Video games">
<meta name="description" content="Games 4 You">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Games 4 You</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/ProductsStyle.css">
    <!-- javascript/jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!--Add the following script at the bottom of the web page (before </body></html>)
Support system using MyLiveChat.com
-->
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" defer="defer" data-cfasync="false" src="https://mylivechat.com/chatinline.aspx?hccid=42206151"></script>
 <script>// disable zoom to keep image fit and always in position
  document.firstElementChild.style.zoom = "reset";
// the above script will disable zoom in and out
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// this will auto change the background image to the following 7 images which are in the root Images/
// this is set to change every five second
    // declare list of backgrounds
    var images = ['bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg'];

    // declare function that changes the background
    function setRandomBackground() {
        // choose random background
        var randomBackground = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

        // set background with jQuery
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("Images/' + randomBackground + '")');
    }

    // declare function that sets the initial background, and starts the loop.
    function startLoop() {
        // Set initial background.
        setRandomBackground();

        // Tell browser to execute the setRandomBackground every 5 seconds.
        setInterval(setRandomBackground, 5 * 1000);
    }

    // One the page has finished loading, execute the startLoop function
    $(document).ready(startLoop);

</script>
<header id="header">
  <div class="container">

<center><img src="Images/Title.png" alt="Title"></div>
</center>
</header>
<center>
<nav>
 <?php
echo "<p> Welcome ".$_SESSION['client_name']."</p>";
 //create connection
   $con = new mysqli("localhost", "student", "student", "cib4003_h00233671_at");
 if ($con->connect_errno) { //failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
 }?>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <ul id="category" >
  <li><a href="Products.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Products.php">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="Productscart.php">View Cart</a></li>
  <li><a href="About.php">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="Settings.php">Settings</a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Logoff</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</center>
<main>

<h3>Available Products</h3>

 <?php
 
 $product = $_GET["RID"];
 $_SESSION["product_name_RID"] = $_GET["RID"];
 $sql="SELECT * FROM  products,reviews WHERE products.Product_Name = '$product' AND reviews.Product_Name = '$product'";
 //$sql="SELECT * FROM  reviews WHERE Product_Name = '$product'";
//  $sql="SELECT * FROM pizza,pizzacart WHERE pizza.Pizza_ID=pizzacart.Pizza_ID AND pizzacart.client_ID=".$_SESSION['client_ID'];

 
 //echo "connected to DB"; 
 //run SQL query
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 //output result
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) //no records found
  {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  products WHERE Product_Name = '$product'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 // echo "<p>no records in DB".mysqli_num_rows($result)."</p>";
 // echo "<p><a href=products.php></a>"; 
 // link has been disable because i am using the <a for something else so i can't force the image to be in the center when using <a
 // so the result will only be image that tell the customers no products found click all or search with different data
  ?>
  
  <table class="table-style-one">
  <tr>
  <th>Product Image</th>
  <th>Product Name</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Product Type</th>
  <th>Console Type</th>
  
  </tr>
  <?php
  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //loops through records
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='".$row['picture']."'/>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Product_Name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Description']."  <center><b><br>".$row['Trailer']."<br></b></center></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Product_Type']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['Console_Type']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
   
  
   //end of loop 
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<p>No Reviews available for this product.<br> To post a review of this product, fill up the below form.</p>";
   
   //end of else
    }
    
  
  
  else
  {
  ?>
  
  <table class="table-style-one">
  <tr>
  <th>Product Image</th>
  <th>Product Name</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Product Type</th>
  <th>Console Type</th>
  </tr>
  
  <?php
  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { //loops through records
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='".$row['picture']."'/>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Product_Name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Description']."  <center><b><br>".$row['Trailer']."<br></b></center></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Product_Type']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['Console_Type']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
   echo "<br>";
   ?>

  
  <?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<table class=table-style-one align=center>";
     //       echo "<tr><th>Review ID</th><td>".$row['Review_ID']."</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>Review By:</th><td>".$_SESSION['client_name']."</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><th>Review Title</th><td>".$row['Review_Title']."</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>Rate:</th><td>".$row['Review_Rate']."/5</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>Review</th><td colspan=2>".$row['Review']."</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>Submitted On</th><td>".$row['Review_Date']."</td></tr>";
   echo "<br>";
   ?>
   <?php
            }
   
  
   //end of loop 
            echo "</table>";
            
   //end of else
  }
  }
  
 
 ?>
 
 <table class="table-style-one" align="center">
<tr>
<form method="POST" action="submitreview.php">
  <!--<th>Product Name:</th><td> <input type="text" size="30" id="ReviewTitle" name="ReviewTitle"  pattern=".{5,}"  required title="5 characters minimum" placeholder="Review Title"></td> -->
  <th>Review Title:</th><td> <input type="text"  required size="30" id="ReviewTitle" name="ReviewTitle"  pattern=".{5,}"  required title="5 characters minimum" placeholder="Review Title">  </td>
  <th>Rate: </th>  
  <td>
  <select name="Review_Rate" required>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
  </td>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4">
 <textarea name="WriteReview" id="WriteReview" required rows="10" cols="50" wrap="physical" placeholder="Write your Review here" style="margin: 0px; width: 437px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
 </td>
 </tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
  <td  colspan="2"><input type="Reset"></td>
  </form> </tr>
</table>
 </h2>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</main>
</body>
<footer>
<p>Made by Humaid Al Ali - H00233671</p>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
        
</footer>
</html>
```

and here the php file where I insert the review into the table

```html
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}  //start session
if (!isset($_SESSION['client_ID'])) {
 //echo "<script>alert('not logged in');</script>";
 header("Location: index.html"  );
 }
?>

<?php
   //new connection
   $con = new mysqli("localhost", "student", "student", "cib4003_h00233671_at");
 if ($con->connect_errno) { //failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
 }

 //success 
//if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
 // run sql 
 
 $sql ="INSERT INTO `cib4003_h00233671_at`.`reviews`(`Review_ID`, `Product_Name`, `client_ID`,  `Review_Title`, `Review_Rate`, `Review`) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['product_name_RID']."', '".$_SESSION['client_ID']."', '".$_POST["ReviewTitle"]."', '".$_POST['Review_Rate']."', '".$_POST['WriteReview']."');";
 if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {echo "<h3> New record created successfully</h3>";
 header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']  );
 } else {
  echo "Error : " . $sql  . "<br>" . $con->error;
 }
 $con->close();
 
 
?>
```

Comment: I do not see a `session_start();` in your first script...if that matters at all.

Comment: i have at the top <?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}  //start session
if (!isset($_SESSION['client_ID'])) {
 //echo "<script>alert('not logged in');</script>";
 header("Location: index.html"  );
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

i just copied the review part

Comment: So both the pages of code you listed here are in one file?

Comment: no, they are two different pages, first one is connected to next one to insert and return, i just updated the first one with full file code

Comment: Ok, well you need to start your session on every page that uses session information.

Comment: Oh, I see you added that to the question details now.

Comment: So ultimately, the first review never makes it to the database at all, or does it make it but not show up?

Comment: it appear in the database only, when another post is made the second and above will only appear,
something like this... First post will only be in database, second post will be in database and web, third will be like second page.. will work perfectly.. the issue is the first post...

Comment: Have you tried just running a single query and loop the results by itself (without all the other code) and see if it shows up then?

Comment: @DaisySensei See my answer. I've also updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

> As the images display, the first review will never show up, only starting from the second and above

That's because you're fetching the first row which includes the first review but you don't display it, rather you starting fetching next reviews and display them. Look at the two conditions in `while` block inside the `else` block.

**Solution:**

To display reviews, you should do something like this:

```
<?php

    // your code

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){

        // your code

    }else{

        echo "<table class='table-style-one'>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Product Image</th>";
                echo "<th>Product Name</th>";
                echo "<th>Description</th>";
                echo "<th>Product Type</th>";
                echo "<th>Console Type</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            // fetch first row, which also contains first review
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><img src='" . $row['picture'] . "'/>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Product_Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "<center><b><br>" . $row['Trailer'] . "<br></b></center></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Product_Type'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Console_Type'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";

        echo "<table class=table-style-one align=center>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Review ID</th>";
                echo "<th>Review By:</th>";
                echo "<th>Review Title</th>";
                echo "<th>Rate:</th>";
                echo "<th>Review</th>";
                echo "<th>Submitted On</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        do{
            // display first review and then fetch rest of the reviews
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Review_ID'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['client_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Review_Title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Review_Rate'] . "/5</td>";
                echo "<td colspan=2>" . $row['Review'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Review_Date'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php
    }


    // your code

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to me to be in your SQL query. It looks as though your SQL query should actually be doing a join on the related column to bring together data across two different tables

```
     $sql="SELECT * 
     FROM products AS p,
     JOIN reviews AS r
     ON p.Product_Name = r.Product_Name
     WHERE products.Product_Name = '$product'";
```

But I think the easiest solution would be to run another query within the table output loop where you get the reviews for the product name you are currently outputting and loop over those.